# Select table a results and set it to array key and fetch other results where a.parent_id = id

Tags: php, mysql

I tried select a table results and set it to array key and fetch all results where `a.parent_id = id`

I tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM category as a
JOIN category as b ON b.parent_id = a.id
WHERE a.parent_id = 0
GROUP BY a.id
```

But it's not a solution.

I have one table:

```
id,name,parent_id
1, Category1, 0
2, Category2, 0
3, Category3, 0
4, Subcategory, 1
5, Subcategory1, 2
6, Subcategory2, 1
7, Subcategory3, 3
```

So i need to get all Categories and fetch all subcategorys. 
Result must look like this:

```
[Category1] => Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [parent_id] => 1
            [name] => tere14
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [parent_id] => 1
            [name] => tere1
        )

)
```

Comment: What does your table look like?  What results does this query show?  What data do you want it to show?  We can't help too much without more info.

Comment: You are using a `GROUP BY` in your query, so multiple rows may wind up being combined together.  Try changing your query to `SELECT a.*, GROUP_CONCAT(b.id) AS child_id, GROUP_CONCAT(b.name) as child`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query was close.  What is happening is that you are using a `GROUP BY` and what that is doing is combining multiple rows into one.  You will get one row per group (in this case, one row per "parent" category).  You need to use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to show all of the values that were combined.

```
SELECT a.*,
  GROUP_CONCAT(b.id) AS child_id, GROUP_CONCAT(b.name) as child
FROM category as a
JOIN category as b ON b.parent_id = a.id
WHERE a.parent_id = 0
GROUP BY a.id
```

DEMO: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/56fed/2

Then in PHP, you can `explode()` the `child_id` and `child` rows to build the structure you want.

If you instead want everything as its own row, you can remove the `GROUP BY`, which will give you a row for each "child" category (and thus multiple for each "parent").

```
SELECT a.*, b.id AS child_id, b.name AS child
FROM category as a
JOIN category as b ON b.parent_id = a.id
WHERE a.parent_id = 0
```

DEMO: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/56fed/5

Comment: Thank you, it work. Only problem is that if don't have subcategory then it don't show that result.

Comment: @OlaviAllik: Then you'll have to change your `JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN`.